# Drupal 8: render view in twig template

Tags: drupal-8

I created view with name "centers" and render that view in twig template with {{ views_embed_view('centers', 'block_1') }}. It gives me nothing in result.
So,please anyone help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above module was depreciated in favour of

#### [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)

> Twig Tweak module provides a Twig extension with some useful functions
> and filters that can improve developer experience.

Ex:    `<dd>{{ drupal_view('centers', 'block_1') }}</dd>`

hope this help you

THANKS