# How to display drupal 8 block in twig template

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I've overridden the drupal front page by creating a page--front.html.twig.
In that twig file I want to **render the user login block** of drupal.
I've seached the internet without finding a clear solution to that problem.
What I've come to understand is to make that possible I have 2 solutions.

1. **Solution 1:** use the  hook_preprocess_HOOK()
2. **Solution 2:** use a plugin like Twig Tweak

Am I Correct ?

I've tried the 2nd solution by installing twig tweak and inserted the below line in my twig template file 
`{{ drupal_entity('block', 'block_id') }}` with `block_id` representing the machine name of the block that can be found in the config page.
It displays nothing and that's normal because when I do a `{{ kint(drupal_entity('block', 'block_id')) }}` to dump the value I got a `NULL` value.
 I don't understand why because I placed the user login form block and configure it to be visible only on the `<front>` page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)

> Twig Tweak module provides a Twig extension with some useful functions
> and filters that can improve developer experience.

Ex:    `<dd>{{ drupal_view('centers', 'block_1') }}</dd>`

hope this help you

THANKS

Comment: A link to the documentation can be helpful too :)

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/twig-tweak-and-views

Comment: same question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971639/drupal-8-render-view-in-twig-template/47131983#47131983

Comment: I finally got it working as expected. Thanks for your help guys. The error was due to a synstax error.